# How to set up SQL Export from SCADA

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering if anyone could point out what this export window (no.3) is trying to ask?
I'm SQL noob and I'm hoping I could get a direction from someone about where to start...
I hope to download data to SQL, basic query and use Python to do more stuff (I'm more familiar with it).

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: _download data to SQL_ Have you installed an SQL Server instance and created a database containing the appropriate tables for your information?

Answer (score 1):

It is a UI of a **Universal Data Link** (UDL) file on a machine with Windows OS.

- First tab contains available installed OLEDB Providers. You need to
  select one of them first.
- Second, i.e. current tab allows to configure database connection. The 'Test Connection' allows to test that connection.